# making event on wrapper element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First, my HTML tag is here

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <form>...</form>
        <div>
            <div class="A"></div>
            <div class="B"><img class="wantToShow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="C"></div>
    </li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is that when I mouse over `<li>`, the small image, `<img class="wantToShow">` , is shown up(like hover).

But when I add event on each `<li>` element the following problems occur.

1. If I use `jQuery.mouseover(<li>, function)`, the whole element in `<li>` shown up whenever I move mouse cursor in `<li>`.
2. If I use `jQuery.mouseenter(<li>, function)`, an element, my mouse cursor enter at first, shown up. In this case, the real problem is that the event do not catch `<li>` but an element in `<li>`.

What can I do for this... Thank you!

Comment: The basic way is set an `id` or `class` for `li`

Comment: this helps you? https://jsfiddle.net/9dref8cp/

Comment: @ElmerDantas So!!! Thank you

Comment: @Aria Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this is what you are after:

```js
$('li').on('mouseover',function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if($('.wantToShow').is(':hidden')) {
    $this.find('.wantToShow').show();
  } else {
    $this.find('.wantToShow').hide();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li>
        <form>This is A</form>
        <div>
            <div class="A"></div>
            <div class="B">
              <img src='https://placebear.com/200/300' class="wantToShow">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="C"></div>
    </li>
    <li>This is B</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @wallah No problem. Happy to help.

Comment: It is also triggered `mouseover` for all `li` in page, isn't it?

Comment: @Aria `mouseover` is triggered for every `li` but we are using `find` and `this` to target `li` with that `image`

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 Yes I know but is it worth to run that code for every `li`,

Comment: @Aria It's not this could be done more effective but as said I was following logic from OP- question